# Can I use scrapy with goose?

Tags: python, scrapy

I read through the Scrapy official tutorial and it wasn't clear to me if I could use some external library to do the article extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. =)

Here is a sample spider to get you started:

```
import scrapy
from goose import Goose

class Article(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    text = scrapy.Field()

class MyGooseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'goose'
    start_urls = [
        'http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2014/06/18/extracting-schema-org-microdata-using-scrapy-selectors-and-xpath/',
        'http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2014/07/17/xpath-tips-from-the-web-scraping-trenches/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        article = Goose().extract(raw_html=response.body)
        yield Article(title=article.title, text=article.cleaned_text)
```

Put this in a `file.py` and run:

```
scrapy runspider file.py -o output.json
```